# $|a|=2^{n-1}$, $b^2\in \langle a\rangle$. By replacing $a$ by another generator of $A$ if necessary, there is $r\leq n-2$ with $b^2=a^{2^r}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Given that $A=\langle a \rangle$, $|a|=2^{n-1}$ and $b\not\in\langle a\rangle,  b^2\in \langle a\rangle$.
>   Replacing $a$ by another generator of $A$ if necessary, we may assume that there is some $r\leq n-2$ with $$b^2=a^{2^r}$$

Note that $b^2=a^k$ for some integer $k$.
If $k=2^r$ for some $r\leq n-2$, then we are done.
Otherwise, write $k=2^pc$ where $(c,2)=1$. Hence $b^2=a^{2^p}a^c$.
Since $(c,2)=1$, we have $\langle a\rangle=\langle a^c \rangle.$
So we get $a^c=a^d$ for some integer $d$. Yet I still do not manage to switch $a^c$ to $a^{2^q}$.

Comment: The statement in the title of the post is wrong, because you may need to replace $a$ by another generator.

Comment: @DerekHolt Editted. By the way, I still can't see how the replacement of generator affect the choice of $b^2$.

Comment: You could for example have $|a|=4$, $b^2=a^3$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ok I get your idea. In this case, label $a^3=x$ we say $b^2\in \langle x \rangle$ and $b^2=c^{2^0}$. So what's wrong with the answer below?

Comment: @DerekHolt I have an idea. Write $b^2=a^{2^pc}=(a^c)^{2^p}$. Then $a^c$ is a generator of $A$. So by labelling $a^c=x$, $b^2\in \langle x \rangle$ and $b^2=x^{2^p}$

Comment: Well $1=b^{2^{n-1}}$ is not true in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Since $b^2 \in \left<a\right> $ then $b^2 = a^{2^l s }$ with some odd $s.$
If $s\neq 1 $ then $1=b^{2^{n-1}} = (b^2)^{2^{n-2}} = a^{2^{n-2 +l} s}= a^{2^{l-1} s} $ hence $2^{n-1} |2^{l-1} s . $ But $l<n$ thus $2|s .$ Contradiction.